# Understanding basic Keras Conv2DTranspose example

Tags: tensorflow, keras

This is definitely a basic question, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly what is going on with Keras's `layers.Conv2DTranspose` function. I have the following three lines:

## Setup

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
...
model.add(layers.Reshape((10, 10, 256)))
model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
assert model.output_shape == (None, 10, 10, 128)
```

The first occurrence of Reshape gets me a tensor of shape [10x10x256].

In the `Conv2DTranspose` layer, somehow I'm sliding a filter of shape [5x5] along this tensor and ending up with a new tensor of shape [10x10x128].

[image: Graphical depiction of what I think this is doing]

## Question

What mathematically is happening to get me from the first tensor [10x10x256] to the second [10x10x128]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost the same as a convolution, but with fancy paddings to get the feeling of doing a backward convolution.

The sliding window in your picture is correctly positioned.
But it's not a "window", it is actually a "sliding block". The size of the block is 256 in depth.

So, it goes multiplying and summing all the channels for each stride.

But then there are 128 different sliding blocks (as you defined in your layer with `filters=128`). Each of these 128 sliding blocks produce separate output channel.

---

Great explanations about transposed convolutions: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Just to make sure I follow: So each layer of the sliding block [5x5] is mat multiplied by a 5x5 section of the entire volume, and then layers are summed at each position? And this is done with completely 128 distinct filters?

Comment: The sliding block is [5x5x256] It's "element-wise" multiplied by the respective section where it's placed, all results of this elementwise multiplication are summed into a single pixel. There are 128 different blocks, thus for every position, you have 128 different resulting pixels. ---- Internally the filters have shape `(5,5,256,128)`, but the "process" is like above.